# Word 2010 VBA Replace within a highlighted range

Tags: vba, ms-word

The following code works, but it performs everything on the *entire document*. I'd like to highlight a block of text, then when I run the macro *only* have it work on the highlighted text. How do I do that? Thanks...

```
Sub DoCodeNumberStyle(numchars As String)

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "(^13)([0-9]{" + numchars + "}) "
        .Replacement.Text = "\1###\2$$$ "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("CodeNumber")
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "###([0-9]{" + numchars + "})$$$"
        .Replacement.Text = "\1"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub

Sub CodeNumberStyle()
    DoCodeNumberStyle ("1")
    DoCodeNumberStyle ("2")
End Sub
```

**PostScript:**

One additional thing I've discovered: if you do more than one find on a Selection, the first find loses/changes the Selection, so the others are no longer bounded by the original Selection (and a wdReplaceAll will continue to the end of the document). To fix this, capture the Selection into a Range. Here's the final version of my method, which now does everything I need, is restricted to the original highlighted selection (even with 3 find-and-replacements), and has also been minimized, code-wise:

```
Sub AAACodeNumberStyleHighlightedSelection()

    With Selection.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Code")
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False

        ' First line:
        .Text = "1   //"
        .Replacement.Text = "###1$$$   //"
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

        ' Rest of lines:
        .Text = "(^13)([0-9]{1,2}) "
        .Replacement.Text = "\1###\2$$$ "
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

        ' Now style the line numbers:
        .Text = "###([0-9]{1,2})$$$"
        .Replacement.Text = "\1"
        .Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("CodeNumber")
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change .Wrap to wdFindStop and this should work for you. I think this might be a minor Word bug; the documentation says that the Wrap value

> sets what happens if the search begins at a point other than the beginning of the document and the end of the document is reached (or vice versa if Forward is set to False) or if the search text isn't found in the specified selection or range.

But it seems like it forces the Find to go to the end of the document rather than taking the selection into account. Anyway, there's no need for wdFindAsk if you only plan to run this on selections.

Comment: That worked -- thank you very much. One of the problems I've always had with VBA is that you can't seem to _just_ find out what values should be assigned to a particular field -- I just see the entire list of wd* definitions, which isn't helpful. How would I have known what the options were for **.Wrap**? Thanks very much for your helpfulness.

Comment: Are you writing your code in the VBA editor that comes with Word? In addition to Intellisense (the little dropdown) you can also click F1 while a keyword is highlighted. That brings up the VBA reference for your version of Word. So, you could highlight Wrap, click F1, get the name of the constant type (in this case WdFindWrap) and either click on it or search for it (sometimes they are linked, sometimes not). You want the WdFindWrap Enumeration. That will list the values and what they mean. In this case 'what they mean' appears to be incorrect, but it's the best place to start.

Comment: I just discovered that if I right-click on the assigned value (such as wdFindStop) and select "List Constants" then it does give me only the ones appropriate for Wrap! Actually this works as well when there's no assigned value, as long as you right-click on the right-hand side of the "=" sign.

Comment: @Christina Thank you. It saved me a lots of time. I had a similar issue when I needed to find/replace only within a particular range.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, found that even when beginning a FIND loop on a range, the range is redefined by FIND, and so continuous loop on .execute goes beyond the original range to the end of the document. wdFindStop stops only at the end of the document, not at the end of the original range.

So, I inserted an IF statement:

do while .find.found
  ...
  If .find.parent.InRange(doc.Bookmarks("BODY").Range) = False Then Exit Do
  ...
  .execute
loop

Answer (score 0):

```
Set myRange = Selection.Range
 myRange.Select
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Apple"
        .Replacement.Text = "Banana"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        '.MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

   myRange.Select
        With Selection.Find
        .Text = "red"
        .Replacement.Text = "yellow"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        '.MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```